# BigQuery - Check if table already exists

Tags: google-api, export, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a dataset in BigQuery. This dataset contains multiple tables.

I am doing the following steps programmatically using the BigQuery API:

1. Querying the tables in the dataset - Since my response is too large, I am enabling allowLargeResults parameter and diverting my response to a destination table.
2. I am then exporting the data from the destination table to a GCS bucket.

Requirements:

- Suppose my process fails at Step 2, I would like to re-run this step.
- But before I re-run, I would like to check/verify that the specific destination table named 'xyz' already exists in the dataset.
- If it exists, I would like to re-run step 2.
- If it does not exist, I would like to do foo.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever look into write disposition? you can actually do something called "write_if_empty", which blocks if there is ANY data on the table. Or "Write_truncate" which will replace existing data with your current one.

Comment: I did look into it. I want to check if table exists before exporting to GCS.. not before writing to a destination table. The write disposition parameter is only available when you want to load data into a table, query a table and copy an existing table. But not while extracting to GCS. This was my understanding. I may be wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: no no you're totally right. Your question just seemed pretty broad, so I wasn't 100% sure where you wanted to catch the problem. Well I mean.... you are using what language? :P We need some meat to this question to be able to look into it. There's definitely a way with the BigQuery API to look if a table exists...

Comment: Are you looking for an API way to do this (for ex, see tables.get at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get)? Or a way to test with the bq client (bq show dataset.table)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a python snippet that will tell whether a table exists (deleting it in the process--careful!):

```
def doesTableExist(project_id, dataset_id, table_id):
  bq.tables().delete(
      projectId=project_id, 
      datasetId=dataset_id,
      tableId=table_id).execute()
  return False
```

Alternately, if you'd prefer not deleting the table in the process, you could try:

```
def doesTableExist(project_id, dataset_id, table_id):
  try:
    bq.tables().get(
        projectId=project_id, 
        datasetId=dataset_id,
        tableId=table_id).execute()
    return True
  except HttpError, err
    if err.resp.status <> 404:
       raise
    return False
```

If you want to know where `bq` came from, you can call `build_bq_client` from here: http://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch12/auth.py

In general, if you're using this to test whether you should run a job that will modify the table, it can be a good idea to just do the job anyway, and use `WRITE_TRUNCATE` as a write disposition.

Another approach can be to create a predictable job id, and retry the job with that id. If the job already exists, the job already ran (you might want to double check to make sure the job didn't fail, however).

Comment: Thank you Jordan. I was able to successfully build a bq client object from valid credentials. Using bq, I was able to implement the doesTableExist function.

Comment: 404 could also mean the resource is not there for a bunch of reasons, while user would think the table simply does not exist. Works now? Maybe. After N years of "working" try to spot the error.

Comment: if you already have an instanciated client, there is an `.exists()` method. See my answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47884257/92471

Comment: "If you want to know where bq came from", the link here seems quite empty?

Answer (score 32):

Alex F's solution works on v0.27, but will not work on later versions. In order to [migrate to v0.28+](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration), the below solution will work.

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound

project_nm = 'gc_project_nm'
dataset_nm = 'ds_nm'
table_nm = 'tbl_nm'

client = bigquery.Client(project_nm)
dataset = client.dataset(dataset_nm)
table_ref = dataset.table(table_nm)

def if_tbl_exists(client, table_ref):
    try:
        client.get_table(table_ref)
        return True
    except NotFound:
        return False

if_tbl_exists(client, table_ref)
```

Answer (score 3):

recently big query introduced so called scripting statements that can be quite a game changer for some flows.

check them out here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting

Now for example to check if table exists you can use something like this:

```
sql = """
  BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 from `YOUR_PROJECT.YOUR_DATASET.YOUR_TABLE) THEN
  SELECT 'table_found';
  END IF;
  EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN

  # you can print your own message like above or return error message 
  # however google says not to rely on error message structure as it may change

  select @@error.message;
END;
"""
```

Comment: I tried something like 
"""BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `a.b.c`) THEN
              DELETE FROM `a.b.c` WHERE date = "2023-03-25";
        END IF;
     END;
      """
but it still complains that the table does not exist. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy:

```
def doesTableExist(bigquery, project_id, dataset_id, table_id):
    try:
        bigquery.tables().get(
            projectId=project_id, 
            datasetId=dataset_id,
            tableId=table_id).execute()
        return True
    except Exception as err:
        if err.resp.status != 404:
            raise
        return False
```

There is an edit in exception.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `exists()` now to check if dataset exists same with table
[BigQuery exist documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.0.x/Dataset#exists)

Comment: The link is bad.

Comment: this is for dataset and NOT table as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

With `my_bigquery` being an instance of class `google.cloud.bigquery.Client` (already authentified and associated to a project):

```
my_bigquery.dataset(dataset_name).table(table_name).exists()  # returns boolean
```

It does an API call to test for the existence of the table via a GET request

Source: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/0.24.0/bigquery-table.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.exists

It works for me using 0.27 of the Google Bigquery Python module

Comment: This method is still absent in google-cloud-bigquery==0.34

Comment: There's an updated method described at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration#table-exists

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

### Inline SQL Alternative

> tarheel's answer is probably the most correct at this point in time

but I was considering the comment from Ivan above that "404 could also mean the resource is not there for a bunch of reasons", so here is a solution that should always successfully run a metadata query and return a result.

> It's not the fastest, because it always has to run the query, bigquery has overhead for small queries

A trick I've seen previously is to query `information_schema` for a (table) object, and `union` that to a fake query that ensures a record is always returned even if the the object doesn't. There's also a `LIMIT 1` and an ordering to ensure the single record returned represents the table, if it does exist. See the SQL in the code below.

- In spite of doc claims that Bigquery standard SQL is ISO compliant, they don't support information_schema, but they do have `__table_summary__`
- dataset is required because you can't query `__table_summary__` without specifying dataset
- dataset is not a parameter in the SQL because you can't parameterize object names without sql injection issues (apart from with the magical `_TABLE_SUFFIX`, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables )

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Inline SQL way to check a table exists in Bigquery

e.g.
print(table_exists(dataset_name='<dataset_goes_here>', table_name='<real_table_name'))
True

print(table_exists(dataset_name='<dataset_goes_here>', table_name='imaginary_table_name'))
False
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from google.cloud import bigquery


def table_exists(dataset_name, table_name):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query = """
        SELECT table_exists FROM
        (
          SELECT true as table_exists, 1 as ordering
          FROM __TABLES_SUMMARY__ WHERE table_id = @table_name
          UNION ALL
          SELECT false as table_exists, 2 as ordering
        ) ORDER by ordering LIMIT 1"""
    query_params = [bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('table_name', 'STRING', table_name)]
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    job_config.query_parameters = query_params

    if dataset_name is not None:
        dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_name)
        job_config.default_dataset = dataset_ref

    query_job = client.query(
        query,
        job_config=job_config
    )

    results = query_job.result()
    for row in results:
        # There is only one row because LIMIT 1 in the SQL
        return row.table_exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for C# below. I don't think there are dedicated methods to check for existence:

```cs
private readonly BigQueryClient _api;

...

public async Task<bool> DatasetExistsAsync(string datasetId)
{
    try
    {
        return await _api.GetDatasetAsync(datasetId) != null;
    }
    catch (GoogleApiException e)
    {
        // specifically we can check for 
        // e.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound
        return false;
    }
}

public async Task<bool> TableExistsAsync(string datasetId, string tableId)
{
    try
    {
        return await _api.GetTableAsync(datasetId, tableId) != null;
    }
    catch (GoogleApiException e)
    {
        // specifically we can check for 
        // e.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound
        return false;
    }
}
```